# How to sort a tuple list in python

Tags: python, arrays, list, sorting

i have a list containing several tuples like this one:

```
(label, count)
```

and i want to sort them by theirs counts, but i have no idea how i can do that. I know python has a built-in function sort() but i don't think i can use it in my case.
I hope someone know how to do this.

example:

```
input: [("label 1", 5), ("label 2", 1), ("label 3", 3), ("label 4", 6)]
output: [("label 4", 6), ("label 1", 5), ("label 3", 3), ("label 2", 1)]
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
a = [("label 1", 5), ("label 2", 1), ("label 3", 3), ("label 4", 6)]
a = sorted(a, key = lambda x: int(x[1]), reverse = True)
```

a becomes

```
[('label 4', 6), ('label 1', 5), ('label 3', 3), ('label 2', 1)]
```

Comment: Why `int(...)` ? :)

Comment: float or int both  will work, infact if you don't give any type it will work since in this example it's already int but for generallity I have added int/float :)